# Handle UITableViewDelegate Events in different Controller

Tags: ios

I am using the UIViewControllerContainment feature in iOS. My container controller is called mainViewController. It consists of menuViewController and contentViewController. The menuViewController is a UITableViewController.

Now, I want that when I select a row in menuViewController I handle an event inside the mainViewController. I have to do all of this without changing the code of menuViewController.

** I am aware I can use delegates to call the mainViewController but using the delegate will alter ** the menuViewController code which I do not want to do.

Comment: So when you say you don't want to change any code in menuViewController, does that include `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?  Because I'm not aware of anything other than `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for detecting when the user has selected a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the menuViewController isn't designed with some sort of delegate or callback block (or you wouldn't be asking the question), you're options are really very limited, and there are no good options, since any option would violate the concept of containment that you're trying to take advantage of.

As I see it, your choices are:

1. Modify the menuVieController to add a delegate or block callback on item selection.  This is the best approach since it keeps the menuViewController well contained and isolated.
2. Subclass the menuViewController, override `didSelectCell...` and do number 1.  Probably need to make sure you call super as well.  This is bad because you're making assumptions about the internal structure of menuViewController and violating containment.
3. Steal the tableView delegate and handle it yourself.  This makes even more assumptions about the internals of menuViewController.

Bottom line, I'd really recommend you rethink the decision not to change menuViewController.

Comment: Thanks David! I went with number 1 and added a delegate from menuViewController back to the mainViewController. The reason I was limiting myself was I was trying to make this into a single control without having to put dependency on the menuViewController.